# Input language stuck in English

Tags: macos, language

I tried to change input language by pressing shortcut <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and also by choosing language on the menu bar. It automatically switches to English language.

The only way I found to fix it by rebooting the Mac.

Maybe someone knows another way?

I'm using English, Japanese and Russian on a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: There is no input source called "English".  Do you actually mean US?

Comment: Does this happen in all apps including TextEdit, Mail, Safari?

Comment: @Tom Gewecke Yes, you're right "US" :) Yes, it happens in all app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting Mac to sleep(holding the power button for couple sec) and then log in again it solves the problem, and I'm able to switch languages again.